# Unittest Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

No much experience in unit tests , someone can help me to review o explain what is expected here.I know concept on unittest, but confused with operacional functioning.

So fo example I have one script with this .

```
def validateName(machineName):
    if machineName:
        pattern = "^[a-z][a-z\d-]+$$"
        if not re.match(pattern,machineName):
           return False 
    return True


def validateIp(inputIp):
    try:
        ipaddress.ip_address(inputIp)
    except ValueError as err:
        raise(err)
```

So for my unittest script i have something like this:  (disregard syntax, i am learning unittest )

```
class TestValidateF(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_validateIpAddress(self):
        IPAdd = "10.75.10.98"
        if isinstance(IPAdd, str) == False:
            message="Error Parameter is empty or has an ivalidad format. Verify it does not star with hiphen "
        #self.assertTrue(ValideIPAdd(IPAdd),True)
            self.assertRaises(IPAdd, message)
    
def test_validateMachineName(self):
    sitename = "machineName"
    if isinstance(machineName, str) == False:
        message="Error Parameter is empty or has an ivalidad format."
    #self.assertTrue(machineName(machineName),True)
        self.assertRaises(machineName, message)
```

Is fine the unittest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first: I think it is a good idea to test your code and to familiarize yourself with something like `unittest`. Also, it is good that you are testing only one thing per test case. Therefore, in general you are on the right track.

However, in your special case I think currently you are not testing anything with your two test cases.

1. You are setting `IpAdd` and `machineName` as `string`s, but add an `if` statement that is only executed when these two variables are not `string`s. Therefore, it looks like the `self.assertRaises` is not executed.
2. `assertRaises` tends to expect an exception, which tends not to be raised when passing valid parameters. Therefore, your two commented `self.assertTrue(...)` statements tend to more reasonable in the two cases you provided.

```py
def test_validateIpAddress(self):
        IPAdd = "10.75.10.98"
        self.assertTrue(ValideIPAdd(IPAdd))
```

3. Try to cover all multiple pathes by also testing if invalid parameters are handled correctly.

```py
def test_invalid_machine_name(self):
        machineName = '9-not_valid%' 
        self.assertFalse(machineName(machineName))
```

4. Test if exceptions are raised when you are expecting them:

```py
def test_validateIpAddress(self):
        IPAdd = None
        with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
                ValideIPAdd(IPAdd)
```

Some more general tips on how to write test cases I personally found where helpful can be found [here](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/tests/). Furthermore, I think it is a good idea to familiarize yourself early in your learning endeavor with [mocks and patches](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html). It makes test cases cleaner and allows you to concentrate on important points of *your* code.

I hope that helps in your future steps.

Comment: Thank u very much for your help. I really appreciate it.  It helped me to continue with other ones.